# Is there software to compute the cohomology of an affine variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, mathematical-software

I have some affine varieties whose cohomology (topological, with $\mathbb{C}$ coefficients) I would like to know. They are very nice, they are all of the form $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ f=0 \}$ for some hypersurface $f$. (In particular, they are smooth.) If I needed to write them as closed subvarieties, I could just write $y f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=1$.

I want software where I type in $f$ and get back the betti numbers. Or at least directions for how to reasonably hack existing software into doing this. Thanks!

Comment: If they are smooth, their de Rham cohomology can be computed as the cohomology of the algebraic de Rham complex (that is, the complex constructed from the module of Kähler differentials *comme on imagine*), by results of Grothendieck, Hartshorne and probably others, no? Since $\Omega^1$ can be constructed easily in Macaulay2, you need to compute its exterior powers and the exterior differential, which should be "easy".


Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question but how do I get Macauley to compute the cohomology of the de Rham complex, since the maps in the de Rham complex are not maps of modules?

Comment: I know that Uli Walther wrote several papers around this question (http://www.math.purdue.edu/~walther/research/index.html ), which means that it certainly feasible in principle. I am not sure if the papers include direct references to ready-made software solutions, or if you have to build it yourself. 

Comment: Thanks Thierry! Following links from Walther's webpage lead me to http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AG/9801114 , which has everything I want to know about the theory. I'm still hunting to find out how much of this I can get prepackaged; I'll report back on what I find if someone else doesn't leave an answer first.

Comment: Macaulay 2 does have the command "deRham" as part of the package "Dmodules", which calculates de Rham cohomology of hypersurface complements in A^n. That package may provide what you need. Walther also wrote a chapter in the Macaulay 2 book (available on the Macaulay 2 web site) that discusses such computations, but it may be faster to go directly to the package rather than to study the chapter.

Comment: Thanks james-parson. That looks like exactly what I want.

Comment: @james-parson Thanks again! This tuned out to be, indeed, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Would you consider answering your own question at some point?  Maybe with the code for an example computation.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Sorry, it's been way too long since I did this for me to still have the code around. But, as I recall, the Macaulay documentation was very clear.